# Xcode: Swift - Connecting TableView to delegate causes tapping on cell to push the Edit Controller twice

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uitableview

The table view is placed on a view controller. When tapping on the a particular cell to view/edit the data it animates push twice with the same edit view controller appearing twice. This is the same case when tapping back button as I have to close the same page twice to go back to tableview cell.

When i accidentally disconnected from the delegate it did not happen and i though somehow it fixed itself. But i could not use swipeaction to delete cells. So i checked for the problem and connected back the delegate.So it started to push the same page twice again and then i realised it has something to do with delegate or data source which is connected by dragging from table view.

Would really appreciate some help on why this is happening and how to solve it.

[I realised when i connect to the delegate the problem occured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUFFg.png)

[Managed to take screenshot of the push to edit VC happening twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi5Vt.png)

[Having to go back twice to reach the tableview VC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJvAG.png)

Comment: I guess you call the segue in code, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using both 'tableView(_:didSelectRow:)' & 'Storyboard Segue' to push Your ViewController.

If your segue is triggered by tapping a cell in your Storyboard, you don’t have to call performSegue() in the tableView(_:didSelectRow:) callback.

You can:

1. Try Deleting 'Storyboard Segue'. or
2. Try getting rid of the tableView(_:didSelectRow:) callback on your code.

It will still perform the Segue, but only once.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @SwiftiOS. Your second suggestion solved the problem. However, when i tried the first sugestion, the edit view controller turned up blank. Im leaving this here for other users who might face the same problem.